# Python add values from multiple columns from one dataframe to another dataframe if it doesn't exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, I need to check if the values in df1 column x1 and column x2 exist in df2 column x. If the value doesn't exists, then add it to df2 column x and NaN to df2 column y.

The following is the what I have, it works but takes too long for large datasets and I feel it could be improved and simplified using Pandas methods.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['a', 'b', 'e'], 'x2':['c', 'd', 'b']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':['d', 'e', 'f'], 'y':['a1', 'b2', 'c3']})

diff = set([*df1[~df1['x1'].isin(df2['x'])]['x1'], *df1[~df1['x2'].isin(df2['x'])]['x2']])

for x in diff:
    df2 = df2.append({"x":x}, ignore_index=True)
```

df1:

```
    x1  x2
0   a   c
1   b   d
2   e   b
```

df2:

```
    x   y
0   d   a1
1   e   b2
2   f   c3
```

Results should be:

```
x   y
0   d   a1
1   e   b2
2   f   c3
3   c   NaN
4   b   NaN
5   a   NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to get it done, using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas-dataframe-melt) + [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append)

```
melt_ = pd.melt(df1, value_name='x')[["x"]]

df2.append(melt_, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('x')
```

---

```
   x    y
0  d   a1
1  e   b2
2  f   c3
3  a  NaN
4  b  NaN
6  c  NaN
```

Comment: This seems the best way to do it with just utilising pandas, only correction would be: `melt_ = pd.melt(df1, value_name='x')[["x"]]

df2.append(melt_, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('x')`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do you want this -

```
from itertools import chain
value_to_add = set(chain(*df1.values)).difference(df2.x.values)
df2 = pd.concat([df2,pd.DataFrame({'x':list(value_to_add)})]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternative `without itertools chain` :

```
value_to_add = set(df1.values.flatten()).difference(df2.x.values)
df2 = pd.concat([df2,pd.DataFrame({'x':list(value_to_add)})]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = pd.concat(
    [
        df2,
        pd.DataFrame({"x": np.setdiff1d(df1, df2["x"])}),
    ]
)
print(df2)  # add .reset_index(drop=True) if you want clean index
```

Prints:

```
   x    y
0  d   a1
1  e   b2
2  f   c3
0  a  NaN
1  b  NaN
2  c  NaN
```